# Access Laptop Weblogic From External Network

Tags: networking, routing

I have installed *Weblogic Server version 12.1.3* on my laptop. From the laptop locally, I can access it via http://laptop_name:7001/console. However, from an external network, this is not accessible. The laptop connects to my network via a *Huawei HG8245Q* make and model router.

**Question:** What are the steps required to configure the Weblogic server to use an external IP or machine name so that I can access it from an outside network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the router or firewall of the network the `laptop_name` is connected, you configure it to forward incoming traffic from the Internet/WAN going to TCP port `7001` to the local IP address and port of the `laptop_name` machine. This functionality within the router or firewall device may be called [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) or sometimes it is referred to as **virtual server**.

Essentially though it can be configured to forward inbound traffic from an ISP router's or firewall appliance's external/WAN/untrusted interface on a specific port to go to the local/private IP address and port of the machine running the **Weblogic** server.

Since you mention the router is of the **Huawei HG8245Q** make and model, according to the ["Fastest Way to Forward Ports on the Huawei HG8245 Router"](https://portforward.com/huawei/hg8245/) you configure this by following this process:

> To open a port for the Huawei HG8245 router you need to:
>
> 1. Setup a **static IP address** on the device or computer you plan on forwarding the ports to.
> 2. Login to your Huawei HG8245 router.
> 3. Find the port forwarding section.
>
>    - Click the **Forward Rules** link.
>    - Click on **Port Mapping Configuration.**
> 4. Create a **port forward** entry or rule.
>
> **Note:** If you are only forwarding a single port then you can enter that same port number into the **External Start Port**, **External End
>   Port**, **Internal Start Port** and **Internal End Port** boxes. If
>   you are forwarding a range of ports then you need to enter the lowest
>   number of the range into the **External Start Port** and **Internal
>   Start Port** boxes and the highest number of the range into the
>   **External End Port** and **Internal End Port** boxes.
>
> **Important:** So this means per the above **Note** section, you will put `7001` into those fields.
>   [image]
>
> [Source](https://portforward.com/huawei/hg8245/)

---

### Server Exposure Security

If the Weblogic server has any vulnerabilities, when you set this up, you are essentially making it accessible to anyone from the Internet.  So you are exposing this server to the outside world so think about this and use caution and/or security best practices accordingly as well with your environment and configuration.

---

### Further Resources

- [Talk:Port address translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3APort_address_translation)
- [NAT vs Port Forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/430692/nat-vs-port-forwarding)

Comment: Stupendous for the wonderful answer, much appreciated.